# Can't get my datagridview to write back to MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2003

I am using MS Access 2003 and vb.net to develop a windows application of inventory management.

I have used datagridview in the form and using FillBytoolstrip option, can filter data using type.

But i have no idea as to how can i update the database to reflect the latest changes in the gridview.

Tried searching but could not find proper and organised answer.

Could you please help me out with this ??

following is the code I have used. I am new to this. Please help !!

```
Private Sub BOM_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Me.PartnoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HemDatabase1DataSet3.partno)

End Sub

Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FillByToolStripButton.Click
        Try
            Me.PartnoTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.HemDatabase1DataSet3.partno, TypeToolStripTextBox.Text)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a TableAdapter `PartnoTableAdapter` to do the database reads (using `Fill` & `FillBy` methods).

Use the same TableAdapter to write back to the database using its `Update` method.